# No executable code found at line …. Android

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-gradle-plugin, breakpoints

I know this question was asked here sometimes, but all solutions which I found didn't work for me.

When I want to debug my program I'm getting information `"No executable code found at line (...)"`.

I've tried:

- Clean project
- Disable instant run
- Add in build.gradle:

  debug {
               debuggable true
               minifyEnabled false
      }

but nothing helped me.
Hope someone here will be able to resolve this problem.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: I've got the exact same issue and have tried everything that you've tried. Very annoying!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add back in the two missing lines, without this they will (I think) use the minified file numbers, either way it messes it up

```
debuggable true
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
```